# Apply rate limiting for sentry server

Tags: sentry

How to apply rate limiting when the sentry server is overloaded

My Sentry init code

```
Sentry.init({
   app,
   dsn: '...',
   integrations: [new BrowserTracing({ tracingOrigins: ['*'] })],
   tracesSampleRate: 0.2,
   autoSessionTracking: false,
   enabled: import.meta.env.VITE_MODE === 'PROD',
   ignoreErrors: ['TypeError', 'Unable to preload', 'timeout', 'Invalid Date'],
});
```

Or how to reduce Sentry server load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which SDK you're using you might have slightly different options available. I'm familiar with the .NET SDK that has [various filtering capabilities](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/configuration/filtering/) that you could use to dymanically filter events in your application before they get sent to Sentry. I think most of the SDKs (Flutter, Javascript, Python etc.) have equivalent capability though.

Alternatively, [Dynamic sampling](https://develop.sentry.dev/dynamic-sampling/the-big-picture/) might be another option.

Comment: thanks and i find rate option in sentry server